# SQL Query to pivot and combine rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table from which I need to derive results as shown below.

[image]

so far I am able to pivot F1  and combine currentvalue & mismatchcount using below sql.

```
SELECT object, GROUP_CONCAT(currentvalue  ,"-", mismatchcount ) as F1
FROM tableT  where freq = F1
GROUP BY object
```

but I need all three freq beside each other as output.

Comment: Please edit your question and include sample data and desired results as *text* tables in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this query:

```
SELECT   object, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(CASE freq WHEN 'F1' THEN
                         CONCAT(currentvalue, "-", mismatchcount) END SEPARATOR " ") as F1,
         GROUP_CONCAT(CASE freq WHEN 'F2' THEN
                         CONCAT(currentvalue, "-", mismatchcount) END SEPARATOR " ") as F2,
         GROUP_CONCAT(CASE freq WHEN 'F3' THEN
                         CONCAT(currentvalue, "-", mismatchcount) END SEPARATOR " ") as F3
FROM     tableT 
GROUP BY object
```

The `CONCAT` function is used to concatenate values from the same record, `GROUP_CONCAT` is used to concatenate such values from different records. The `CASE WHEN` expression is evaluated for several records (with different values for `freq`) and thus returns several values. But of those values the non-null values need to concatenated. The separator is set to the space.

Comment: Hi Trincot I coud not get the use of MAX from your sql statement. why is it used?

Comment: Just added an explanation about the use of `MAX` in my answer.

Comment: Thanks trincot. But the freq column can have  repeated values with different currentvalue and mismatchcount. I have updated the picture. please note.

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly. Now you will tell me you need the multiple values in a certain order? In that case add the `order by ` clause in the `group_concat` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) you nailed it!!